# ViewerCertificateException - Cloudfront not aware of wildcard on Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a cloudfront distribution that I want to serve the following domains & I am trying to list as CNAMEs:

```
domain.com
www.domains.com
domain.ca
www.domain.ca
```

Now my certificate has *.domain.com and *.domain.ca and is approved.
But when I tried to add either "domain.com" or "domain.ca" to my cloudfront CNAMEs, I get this error.
Why do I get this?

ViewerCertificateException: The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard certificate `*.domain.ca` **does not cover** `domain.ca`. Same case for `domain.com`. You need to re-issue your certificate to include both the wildcards and the `domain.com` and `domain.ca`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html):

> Also note that *.example.com protects only the subdomains of example.com, it **does not protect the bare or apex domain** (example.com). However, you can request a certificate that protects a bare or apex domain and its subdomains by specifying multiple domain names in your request. For example, you can request a certificate that protects example.com and *.example.com.